# Tinkerpop Select neighbours grouped by the vertex they are neighbour with range step

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, tinkergraph

I want to select all `l` labelled vertices along with their `t` labelled vertices grouped by their neighbours. Also I want to apply a limit on the length of the neighbours.
For ex for neighbour limit = 2 something like below should be output.

```
[
{"l1",[t1,t2]},
{"l2",[t3]},
{"l3",[]}
]
```

For ex for neighbour limit = 1 something like below should be output.

```
[
{"l1",[t1]},
{"l2",[t3]},
{"l3",[]}
]
```

grelify link https://gremlify.com/xun4v83y54/1

```
g.addV('Vertex').as('1').property(single, 'name', 'l1').property(single, 'label', 'l').
  addV('Vertex').as('2').property(single, 'name', 'l2').property(single, 'label', 'l').
  addV('Vertex').as('3').property(single, 'name', 'l3').property(single, 'label', 'l').
  addV('Tag').as('4').property(single, 'name', 't1').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addV('Tag').as('5').property(single, 'name', 't2').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addV('Tag').as('6').property(single, 'name', 't3').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addE('connected').from('1').to('4').
  addE('connected').from('1').to('5').
  addE('connected').from('2').to('6')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `group()` would work well here:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('label','l').
......1>   group().
......2>     by('name').
......3>     by(out().limit(2).values('name').fold())
==>[l1:[t1,t2],l2:[t3]]
gremlin> g.V().has('label','l').
......1>   group().
......2>     by('name').
......3>     by(out().limit(1).values('name').fold())
==>[l1:[t1],l2:[t3]]
```

Note that the second `by()` modulator is a reducing operation for the collected items you grouped. In there you may manipulate that collection further as needed. To demonstrated I modified your data a bit:

```
g.addV('Vertex').as('1').property(single, 'name', 'l1').property(single, 'label', 'l').
  addV('Vertex').as('2').property(single, 'name', 'l2').property(single, 'label', 'l').
  addV('Vertex').as('3').property(single, 'name', 'l3').property(single, 'label', 'l').
  addV('Tag').as('4').property(single, 'name', 't1').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addV('Tag').as('5').property(single, 'name', 't2').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addV('Tag').as('6').property(single, 'name', 't3').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addV('Tag').as('7').property(single, 'name', 't4').property(single, 'label', 't').
  addE('connected').from('1').to('4').
  addE('connected').from('1').to('5').
  addE('connected').from('2').to('6').
  addE('next').from('2').to('7')
```

In the following case I just used `union()` to create two lists - one of each "type":

```
gremlin> g.V().has('label','l').
......1>   group().
......2>     by('name').
......3>     by(union(out("connected").limit(1).values('name').fold(),
......4>              out("next").limit(1).values('name').fold()).
......5>        fold())
==>[l1:[[t1],[]],l2:[[t3],[t4]],l3:[[],[]]]
```

but you could use other [collection manipulation techniques](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#collections) to get it into other forms of course.

Comment: is there a way to select multiple types of neighbours. For ex: 
```
g.V().has('label','l').
 group().
 by('name').
by(out("oneType").limit(1).values('name').fold()).
by(out("secondType").limit(1).values('name').fold())
```